# How to get a tag inner using getElementById after specified item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get a tag inner-text of `<a>`-tag that are next after **red** span?

Here's example source code:

```
<p>
    Text1<br>
    <span style="color:blue">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</p>
<p>
    Text1<br>
    <span style="color:red">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a>
</p>
<p>
    Text1<br>
    <span style="color:blue">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</p>
    <p>
    Text1<br>
    <span style="color:red">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://myspace.com">myspace</a>
</p>
```

**Here's output**:

[image]

I tried to use document.get.Element.ByTagName, but I don't really know how to use it for  elements which are following only after red "span".

Maybe, I should use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use classes, instead of in-line CSS, you could just CSS:

```
.redStyle = {
    color: red;
}

.blueStyle {
    color: blue;
}

// style the elements:

.redStyle + br + a, /* multiple adjacent-sibling combinators are required
                       if you insist on retaining the 'br' elements */
.redStyle ~ a {
    color: green;
}
```

This would, of course, require HTML such as:

```
<p>
    Text1<br>
    <span class="blueStyle">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</p>
<p>
    Text1<br>
    <span class="redStyle">span</span><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">Bing</a>
</p>
```

To get the actual nodes, or a property of those nodes, with JavaScript:

```
function follows(target, cName) {
    while (target.previousSibling) {
        if (target.previousSibling.className && target.previousSibling.className.indexOf(cName) > -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            target = target.previousSibling;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    relevantLinks = [],
    relevantText = [];

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (follows(links[i], 'redStyle')) {
        // this adds to the store of relevant links in which you're interested
        relevantLinks.push(links[i]);
        // you could act on them directly, but storing them
        // allows for further use at a later time (if required)
    }
}
for (var i = 0, len = relevantLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
    // iterating over the relevant links/elements, pushing their text
    // into another array to store that text
    relevantText.push(relevantLinks[i]['textContent' || 'innerText']);
}    

console.log(relevantText);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hTNmz/1/).

Of course, in most modern browsers, if you do use the class-names (again, instead of in-line CSS) you could simply use `document.querySelectorAll()` to retrieve a nodeList of relevant elements, and iterate over that directly:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    relevantLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.redStyle ~ a'),
    relevantText = [];

for (var i = 0, len = relevantLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
    relevantText.push(relevantLinks[i]['textContent' || 'innerText']);
}

console.log(relevantText);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hTNmz/3/).

Comment: Warn him about the separating `<br/>` tag

Comment: @david-thomas: You haven't understood me. I have to get a tag inner-text using getElementById(or any other method). Sorry, I formulated my question incorrectly. I have already updated it.